# Javers saves commitDate and commitDateInstant as String. How to set them as LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, javers

I am storing the entity audit log to mongodb using javers. Each time I make a commit to mongodb, Javers saves the timestamp as String. But I want to save it as LocalDateTime Object. Is there any way to do this?

```java
    public <T> void saveAuditLog(T entity) throws TokenDecryptionException {
            LogMetaDataDTO logMetaDataDTO = this.logFactory.createApplicationLogMetaData();
    
            try {
                String author = this.logHelperService.getCurrentUserIdFromRequestContext();
                this.javers.commit(author == null ? "" : author, entity, this.auditLogUtils.convertObjectToMap(logMetaDataDTO));
                logger.debug("Saved to audit log!");
            } catch (Exception var4) {
                throw var4;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you mean can you store a LocalDateTime object in mongo, no. You can serialize one to a String and save that, and deserialize it back when reading from mongo.

Comment: By the way, `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* data type to record a moment. That class purposely lacks a time zone or offset from UTC. With only a date and a time of day, we do not know if a `LocalDateTime` was meant for that time on that date in Tokyo, or in Toulouse, or in Toledo — these would all be different moments, several hours apart. Use `Instant` instead, or if going through JDBC, `OffsetDateTime`.